# How to understand the relation between view and controller in Rails? Is view part of the controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

What confuses me is, for example, if we have a method `index` defined in the controller and within `index` there's a instance variable `@var`, we can access `@var` directly in index.html.erb without specifying anything. So is view part of the controller? Can the html.erb file in view access local variables in the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controllers are the event handlers that process incoming requests from the browser whilst concurrently processing data that is in the models. The controller will handle request from the user interaction i.e. keyboard input or click event from the mouse. The response of the controller is then outputted in the views. So if you was to have a `UserController` that had an `index` action in your `index.html.erb` if you wanted to access these `users` by looping round them you would have some sort of similar set up.

**Controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def index
   @users = User.all #Returns an array of all users

   respond_to do |format|
   format.html { render "users/_users", :locals => { :users=> @user } }} 

    end
```

**Index.html.erb**

```
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <tr>
        <td> user.name</td>
      </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Update:**

Okay so I think you meant sending a local variable and accessing it in the view. Further to this it is known that using local variable seems to advisable in a partial that can be used application-wide to avoid dependencies. So if this is the case and you wanted to pass local variables into a partial you would use `:locals` to keep it clean. Example follows:

```
render :partial => 'my_partial', :locals => { :some_variable => some_variable, :value=> 'value' }
```

Hope this clears things up

Comment: So since the view can access instance variables, can it access local variables in the controller? That's the main point of my question. (I may not be good at phrasing my question.)

Answer (score 0):

Views are separate objects from controllers in Rails. The controller includes its instance variables to the view's context when rendering a view. You should consider this to be a special argument passing convention, rather than a violation of encapsulation (a view accessing private variables of a controller). Rails uses this convention to avoid reflecting the view's (fragment) structure into the fields passed from the controller to the view. Since values are passed from the controller to the view in a relatively unstructured way, we have the flexibility to restructure a view without necessarily causing much change to the controller.